# How to pass parameters to Oracle DbContext FromSql in Net Core

Tags: .net-core, oracle-manageddataaccess

```
var list = db.SomeModels.FromSql("select id from table1 where rownum < :r",10).ToList();
```

gives me

> System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid parameter binding Parameter name: r'

What am I missing. Can't find any docs on that

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
var row = new OracleParameter("r", OracleDbType.Int32);
row.Value = 10;

var list = db.SomeModels
    .FromSql("select id from table1 where rownum < :r", new object[] { row })
    .ToList();
```

To add multiple parameters, add more `OracleParameter` objects to the object array:

```
var row = new OracleParameter("r", OracleDbType.Int32);
row.Value = 10;

var nameParameter = new OracleParameter("name", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
nameParameter.Value = "John";

var list = db.SomeModels
    .FromSql("select id from table1 where rownum < :r and firstname = :name", new object[] { row, nameParameter })
    .ToList();
```

Unfortunately, like yourself I haven't found any proper documentation for it. I will edit the answer when I do.

The following code will also work (tested with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core v2.19.31 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v2.2.6):

```
var list = db.SomeModels
    .FromSql("select id from table1 where rownum < {0}", 10)
    .ToList()
```

Comment: did you test yourself?

Comment: @Toolkit sorry about that, was thinking in EF core too much. Updated the answer to work with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Still looking for actual documentation on using parameters and FromSql using oracle's ef core driver.

Comment: @Toolkit plus double checked with actual testing this time lol